# Django - Build a model filter from string

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

Is it possible to filter models using string arguments?

Consider the following filter:

```
some_model.filter(parameter__gte = x)
```

I want to build that filter argument using strings.

eg.

```
if equality == ">" and argument == x: query = "{0}__gte".format(parameter)
```

Then filter using that built argument.

```
some_model.filter(query = x)
```

Is something along those lines possible without using raw sql?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Use your strings as the keys and values of a dictionary, then pass that dictionary to `filter` using the `**` operator to use them as keyword argument pairs. Using your above example:

```
filter_arguments = {query: x}
some_model.filter(**filter_arguments)
```